# Magento How to change onepage checkout order , change review and payment order positions?

Tags: php, magento

I want to change the order of Magento one page checkout , as you know the default order is - ['login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review'], but I want to change this order as per my requirement to ['login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'review', 'payment'].

I have tried but did not get the solution.

When I have changed the order from Abstract.php file then the order came in fronted as per my requirement but its functionality did not work.

Please suggest any answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that simple, i have done it before. 

First you need to realize that the onepage checkout flow's logic is designed as ['login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review'] in order. In the review section, it will ,for example, checking whether it need to redirect to payment gateway according to the payment method chosen in the payment method step. 
Another thing is that you still need to recollect the total after pressing 'place order' button in the last step. You need to dig hard to find out those.

In order to change as you stated, you need to change view(template), controller(or in the ajax way as i recalled) , and probably the opcheckout.js